# Can't find " related" options in "query" section in WordPress ,trying to build single page post, want to show relevant posts?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg, wordpress-shortcode

Can't find " related" options in "query" section in WordPress ,trying to build single page post, want to show relevant posts, option not there in "select post by " ? not using any plugins , hosting site " siteground"
kindly help

I'm trying to get similar data by category (eg : 'news' only from the category list, same post tags ).

Comment: There is no "relevant" option as that's a subjective thing. You need to define what "relevant" is first (eg. same/similar keywords in title? same category? same post tag(s)?) and then you can try querying posts according to said criteria.

Comment: Thank you for your clearance , yes I'm trying to get similar data by category (eg : 'news' only from the category list with the news tags ).

Comment: If so then you could use either of the category parameters to get posts from the same category: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters

Comment: I really appreciate your support here .  actually the problem is simpler than you thinking , I am using WordPress Interface , (nube ) , just can not find the options from drop down .